Keyboard swapping from emoji to alpha not resizing view
When you open the keyboard, the textfield moves up and the bottomnav is hidden.When switching to the emoji keyboard, it likewise adjusts automatically. However, when going from emoji to alpha again, the view is not resized, and the bottomnav becomes visible.
How can I tell the app to update the view?
You can see the 'dash'... etc which is the bottom nav
Is there a way to do this without having to monitor and basically do this manually for just this transition? It does it automatically when a kb appears, disappears, and gets larger, but not smaller?
